# Export Power BI Report from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, reporting, sharepoint-online, powerbi-embedded

Power BI report can be exported from https://app.powerbi.com/ page using inbuilt Export feature.

I have a requirement to provide same functionality from within SharePoint Online page, where this report is embedded. Please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Export To File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile) / [Export To File In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofileingroup) API.

1. When the Export-To-File API is called, it triggers an export job.
2. After triggering the export job, you can use the Polling API ([Get Export To File Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getexporttofilestatus) / [Get Export To File Status In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getexporttofilestatusingroup)) to track the job until it is complete.
3. When the export job is complete, the Polling API call returns a Power BI URL for getting the file (the URL is available for 24 hours). You can also download it by calling [Get File Of Export To File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getfileofexporttofile) / [Get File Of Export To File In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getfileofexporttofileingroup) API.

The API supports concurrent export job requests. The number of jobs you can run at the same time, depends on the SKU your report resides on, as detailed in [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#concurrent-requests) (i.e. it requires a dedicated capacity - Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded).

For example, here is how you can use the API with PowerShell code:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
$username = "account@example.com" 
$password = "SuperStrongPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$groupId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$reportId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$format = "PDF" # or PNG, or PPTX. For paginated reports can be CSV, DOCX, IMAGE (i.e. page definition plus file format - BMP, EMF, etc.), MHTML, XLSX or XML
$saveToFolder = "D:\"

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential
$settings = @{ includeHiddenPages = $false; locale = "en-us" }
$powerBIReportConfiguration = @{ settings = $settings }
$export_body = @{ format = $format; powerBIReportConfiguration = $powerBIReportConfiguration }
$export_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/reports/$reportId/ExportTo" -Method Post -Body ($export_body | ConvertTo-Json)
$export_response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $export_response
$exportId = $export_response_json.id

Write-Output "Polling export status..."
$maxPollCount = 500
$exportSucceeded = $false
do
{
    $maxPollCount = $maxPollCount - 1
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    $status_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$groupId/reports/$reportId/exports/$exportId" -Method Get
    $status_response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $status_response
    $status = $status_response_json.status
    $percentComplete = $status_response_json.percentComplete
    Write-Output "Status: $status, percent complete: $percentComplete (retries left: $maxPollCount)"
    if ($status -eq "Succeeded")
    {
        $exportSucceeded = $true
        $resourceLocation = $status_response_json.resourceLocation
        $reportName = $status_response_json.reportName
        $resourceFileExtension = $status_response_json.resourceFileExtension
        $outFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($saveToFolder, $reportName + $resourceFileExtension)
    }
}
until($exportSucceeded -or $maxPollCount -le 0)

Write-Output "Downloading export..."
$download_response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $resourceLocation -Method Get -OutFile $outFile
Write-Output "Download completed."
Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```